# Running a react app in development mode when App is embedded in Drupal

Tags: reactjs, drupal, drupal-8

Not sure if this is possible and not really sure where to start.

I have taken over maintenance of a React App that is embedded inside a Drupal 8 build. It's built as a custom module and running from a specific route on the website. Ex: https://example.com/portal/{react-app}

Currently if I need to make any code changes I have to rebuild the app before I can see it render on the screen, using `npm run build`.

I'm trying to have this app run in development mode so it can watch code changes and render automatically, but the problem is it forgets about the Drupal side when doing this. None of the Drupal dependencies are being loaded which results in a broken app.

I'm running this inside a Docker container using port 80. The react app runs on port 3000 when in development mode. Changing Docker to run on port 3000 doesn't work because the React app complains about port 3000 being in use.

Is there a way I can still run the app in development mode using port 3000, while still having Drupal running in my container on port 80?

Example config:
https://example.com/portal/{react-app}

```
  version: VERSION
  js:
    /modules/custom/{react-app}/js/build/static/js/main.chunk.js: {}
    /modules/custom/{react-app}/js/build/static/js/vendor.chunk.js: {}
    /modules/custom/{react-app}/js/build/static/js/runtime-main.js: {}
  css:
    theme:
      /modules/custom/{react-app}/js/build/static/css/main.chunk.css: {}
```